# Do we need to override hashcode method?

Tags: java

I was looking at the [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and also reading couple of questions in StackOverflow on the same topic.

`equals()` method is used to determine the equality of two objects.

Basically, if you want to `store an object in a collection (Map, Set, List)` then you have to implement equals and hashCode methods according to the contract defined in the documentation.

**Correct me if i am wrong**, If i am not storing my Class inside an collection, then i don't need to over-ride the `hashcode` method as the `equals` method would be more than enough.

Comment: It depends on what you intend to use it for. If you just want to do your own value equality checking, then you'll be fine without hashCode. But I don't think it's a good idea to assume your object will never, ever be in a collection.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that Eclipse at least, and possibly other IDEs, will generate a hashCode method for you on request.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct. However, if you later (when the shortcut is long forgotten) put it into a Map or Set, things will crash badly.

Comment: It won't *crash* if your class implements `Comparable` and you add it into a `TreeMap` (as key) or `TreeSet`.

Comment: Unfortunately not - a *crash* would be easier to diagnose than what is likely to *actually* happen, which is that you just won't be able to find objects in the map.

Comment: @JonSkeet: can you explain your statement little bit more, i did not get the exact meaning behind it.

Comment: @Kevin: If your type ever *is* used as the key in a hash-based collection, and you've unfortunately forgotten that you forgot to override hashCode, you may well find it takes a *long* time to work out what the problem is, because the symptoms won't be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to override `hashCode` if you are overriding `equals` but it is not mandatory. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by `HashMap`.

**Note**: So if you are sure that you or anyone else will never use your class object to be stored in a hashed collection then skip it. Otherwise override it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't put your object into HashMap or similar Collection / Map types then you don't to override the hashCode function in your class.

Comment: You don't *have* to do anything, but what's best practice is a different story.

Comment: But the question is not about best practice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) javadoc:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

This means, if you will override `equals`, then it will be good to also override `hashCode` to follow this contract, but it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `hashCode()` will help in a healthy categorization for all *Hash based implementations* in Java. The buckets will distributed depending on the hashCode() method's value.